# Read from 2 Different file to be 2 dimensional array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

How to read two .txt files and turn these 2 files to a 2d array?

I already have a code like this :

```
var fs = require('fs')
file = './text1.txt'
fs.readFile(file,'utf-8', (e,d) => {
  textByLine = d.split('\r\n');
  console.log("test : " + textByLine[1])
})
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47807876/reading-and-storing-a-text-file-into-an-array-with-javascript)

I succeeded to store the file in a 1d array but now I have 2 files and I want to store them in a 2d array.
How to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can have a variable at top with an empty array, after you read the files and push that result to that variable , like this:

```
const 2dArray = [];
const fillArray = (path)=> {
  fs.readFile(path,'utf-8', (e,d) => {
    2dArray.push(d.split('\r\n')) // the result is already an array.
  });
});
```

after that you can call each file like this :

```
// read the files and push the result to the variable 2dArray
fillArray('./text1.txt'); 
fillArray('./text2.txt');

//you can read the 1st result of your 1st file array like this
const firstPartOfArray = 2dArray[0][0];  // text1 first result value
```

if you don't need to have the result files in order i strongly recommend to use async function.

also you can use thinks like [fs-jetpack package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-jetpack) to handle this, or [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob)